# Nuxt 3 can't load Material Design Icons with Vuetify in production build

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3 with Vuetify 3 and deploying with Amplify. In my web application, in local build the v-icon can display the icon correctly. But in the deployed app, the icons sometimes doesn't display properly.

[Correct icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDZOq.png)

[Incorrect icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpF1t.png)

I checked the network tab when the error happened but the font is already loaded

[Network tab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QUJq.png)

[Network tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJTmW.png)

Can anyone help me with this issue?

This is how i use the v-icon of Vuetify:

```js
<v-icon icon="mdi-calendar-month-outline" />
```

I've installed @mdi/font and vuetify

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.2.96",
    "vuetify": "^3.2.1"
}
```

My nuxt config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  css: [
    'vuetify/styles',
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
  ],
})
```

My Vuetify plugin:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    icons: {
      defaultSet: 'mdi',
      aliases,
      sets: {
        mdi,
      },
    },
    components: {
      ...labs,
      ...components,
    },
    directives,
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

My Amplify build setting:

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn generate 
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: '.output/public'
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```